# Simple qtip2 example does not work

Tags: javascript, html, qtip2

I'm trying to get a simple qtip2 demo running but it wont work need help.
qtip2 is a framework that allows to create individual tooltips.
if you hover over the link a small yellow box should appear.

all files are in the same folder.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>My site</title>

<!-- CSS file -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.qtip.css" />

</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.imagesloaded.pkg.min.js"></script>


<a href="#test" title="My tooltip text">Sample link</a>

<script>
// self executing function here
(function() {

   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here
 $('a[title]').qtip();
})();
</script>

<a href="#test" title="My tooltip text">Sample link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are there errors in the console? I guess the sources are not loaded properly...

Comment: is there any way to check if they are loaded ?

Comment: there are developer tools available in your browser... just google it. Or look inside of the menu... there should be something like developer tools...then there will be a little window inside of your browser and a tab called console...there you click and hopfully see errors

Comment: tools like firebug ?

Comment: firebug shows me all the functions from the files i have imported

Comment: so no errors shown?

Comment: it says "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: aha! So you need to load the libraries! Take the files: jquery.min.js, jquery.qtip.js, jquery.imagesloaded.pkg.min.js and put it into your folder where the html file is located... and it should load properly...also the css file

Comment: all the files are already in the same folder

Comment: i have added "<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">" to head area and the erros disappeared

Comment: okay thats also a way to go!

Comment: but its not working it still only displays the standart design and not the qipts one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed unnessesary codes like the imagesloaded and replace the jQuery link you have with a CDN version.

And it works.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My site</title>
<!-- CSS file -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.qtip.css" />
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">          </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<a href="#test" title="My tooltip text">Sample link</a>
<script>
// self executing function here
(function() { $('a[title]').qtip(); })(); </script>
<a href="#test" title="My tooltip text">Sample link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad we could help.